# 08 Jetta automatic passenger axle replacement

Tags: vw, jetta, cv-axle

Looking for a video or pictures of replacing an 08 jetta passenger side axle. Or a good writeup.

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Comment: A Haynes manual?

Comment: If you sign up to be a member at autozone.com they have free repair guides and trouble shooting techniques for free

Answer (score 1):

Here's the general steps to do the job (without being too anal about it):

Disassembly

1. With the car still on the ground, break the lug nuts free, but don't loosen them all the way.
2. Jack the front end up (side you're going to remove the axle from) and place on a jack stand.
3. Remove lug nuts and tire.
4. Remove center bolt which holds the axle into the hub with a 27mm socket.
5. Remove tie rod end nut with 18mm socket, then free the tie rod end from the steering arm. Place the nut back onto the tie rod end to prevent loss of nut or damage to the treads of the tie rod end.
6. Remove three 16mm nuts holding the ball joint to the lower control arm.
7. Using a pry bar, separate the ball joint from the lower control arm.
8. Pull the hub/knuckle out, which should allow you to remove the outer CV joint (CVJ) from the hub.
9. Noting the distance of the inner Using a pry bar between the transmission case and the inner CVJ, pop the axle free of the transmission.

Reassembly

10. Align the new axle at the transmission and insert it. You should feel/hear a click as it homes into position. It should be fairly much flush with the transmission and look as the old one did before removal.
11. Place the outer CVJ into the hub.
12. Align, then insert, the three bolts of the ball joint into the lower control arm. Replace and tighten the three nuts to 45 lb-ft.
13. Tighten the 27mm bolt to 52 lb-ft, then an additional 90°. **NOTE:** This is a torque to yield bolt and should be replaced at time of assembly.
14. Replace the wheel back onto the car with lug bolts snug.
15. Lower car to ground.
16. Torque the lugs in two steps to 100 lb-ft.

Please note, if you have access to impact tools, this goes a lot faster. If not, 1/2" drive ratchet/sockets/breaker bar will most likely be needed due to the amount of torque involved.